# Microsoft Graph Group query does not expand relationships when $select is present

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to query group owners along with a few properties of the groups. When I add `$select` the `owners` property gets dropped. I need `$select` to reduce the amount of data returned. Any way to achieve both?

```
/beta/groups?$expand=owners&$filter=startswith(mailNickname, 'rtan')&$top=999&$select=mailEnabled,owners
```

Response (has `mailEnabled` but is missing `owners`):

```json
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#groups(mailEnabled,owners)",
  "value": [
    {
      "mailEnabled": true
    },
    {
      "mailEnabled": true
    },
    {
      "mailEnabled": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, this smells like a bug in the `/groups` API. I can confirm that, at the moment, you can either `$select` _or_ `$expand` but _not both_. Your call should work (although you should always handle paging instead of `$top=999`, `top` isn't a reliable way to "get everything").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One *workaround* at the moment to combine both `$select` and `$expand` for `/groups` endpoint would be to specify asterisk (*) character in `$select` expression.

For example, the following query:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups?expand=owners&select=owners,*
```

will return *all* the group details along with `owners`

Comment: @MatthieuMaitre But the response is literally the same as when you don't specify $select. Did you manage to reduce output size and select only specific group attributes along with owners?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Matthieu for pointing this out.  If you try the query without `$select` you'll see that the expansion does work.  This issue is one of our [documented known issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#query-parameters). I'm not saying that doesn't make things better — clearly in this case `$select` and `$expand` in the same request should just work.

Also @Marc points out, it's either or, but this isn't just a `groups` issue.  It's across the board for all directory based entity types (users, groups, devices, applications, service principals, etc).

I don't have an ETA for a fix I'm afraid, but it is something that is being worked on.

Comment: Any progress on this issue? Because more than a year later it still doesn't seem to be working.