# Microsoft Graph API - Get group owner details along with group details in azure

Tags: rest, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-resource-group

In Azure I could find an API for getting the group details like as shown below

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups
```

which will gives me all the group details like as shown below

```
{  
  "value": [  
    {  
      "id": "/groups/53c765632095310385020001",  
      "name": "Administrators",  
      "description": "Administrators is a built-in group. Its membership is managed by the system. Microsoft Azure subscription administrators fall into this group.",  
      "builtIn": true,  
      "type": "system",  
      "externalId": null  
    },  
    {  
      "id": "/groups/53c765632095310385020002",  
      "name": "Developers",  
      "description": "Developers is a built-in group. Its membership is managed by the system. Signed-in users fall into this group.",  
      "builtIn": true,  
      "type": "system",  
      "externalId": null  
    },  
    {  
      "id": "/groups/53c765632095310385020003",  
      "name": "Guests",  
      "description": "Guests is a built-in group. Its membership is managed by the system. Unauthenticated users visiting the developer portal fall into this group.",  
      "builtIn": true,  
      "type": "system",  
      "externalId": null  
    }  
  ],  
  "count": 3,  
  "nextLink": null  
}
```

but the problem is I need group owner details also along with group details. At present I calls another API as shown below for getting the group owner details

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupId}/owners
```

Is there any API or any other way in which I can get the group owner details along with groups details in one shot in azure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft Graph API supports some optional query parameters like select, filter, expand, search etc. which help in controlling what data you get back in response to your query. You can read about them [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters)

**[expand parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#expand-parameter)** might be helpful for your use case.

I quickly tried out a query like below from [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/graph/graph-explorer/) and it returns the group information as well as owners collection for each group.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$expand=owners
```

Disclaimer: Microsoft Docs for expand parameter have a note which says something like

> With Azure AD resources that derive from directoryObject, like user
>   and group, $expand is only supported for beta and typically returns a
>   maximum of 20 items for the expanded relationship.

Although, above mentioned query, which uses v1.0 did work fine for me at least from Graph explorer. So do test as much as possible (with high number of groups as well) before starting to rely on it. I'll also update back in case I find more up to date documentation regarding the same.

Here is the exact response I got for query I mentioned above. It's pretty big, I just included 2 groups and removed others, so that you get an idea.

Important part is to notice that owners collection is present along with groups. Notice the first group has no owners assigned, but second group has 2 users as owners.

**REQUEST**

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$expand=owners
```

**RESPONSE**

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#groups",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "xxxx-redacted-49b4e13fcf0f",
            "deletedDateTime": null,
            "classification": null,
            "createdDateTime": "2018-09-26T04:41:10Z",
            "creationOptions": [],
            "description": null,
            "displayName": "Business",
            "groupTypes": [],
            "mail": null,
            "mailEnabled": false,
            "mailNickname": "xxxx-redacted-88df-adf033b7f545",
            "onPremisesLastSyncDateTime": null,
            "onPremisesSecurityIdentifier": null,
            "onPremisesSyncEnabled": null,
            "preferredDataLocation": null,
            "proxyAddresses": [],
            "renewedDateTime": "2018-09-26T04:41:10Z",
            "resourceBehaviorOptions": [],
            "resourceProvisioningOptions": [],
            "securityEnabled": true,
            "visibility": null,
            "onPremisesProvisioningErrors": [],
            "owners": []
        },
        {
            "id": "xxxx-redacted-9316-a5acea4412d8",
            "deletedDateTime": null,
            "classification": null,
            "createdDateTime": "2018-09-26T04:19:29Z",
            "creationOptions": [],
            "description": null,
            "displayName": "DevOps",
            "groupTypes": [],
            "mail": null,
            "mailEnabled": false,
            "mailNickname": "xxxx-redacted-4f18-b2b1-e5a7b80d19ea",
            "onPremisesLastSyncDateTime": null,
            "onPremisesSecurityIdentifier": null,
            "onPremisesSyncEnabled": null,
            "preferredDataLocation": null,
            "proxyAddresses": [],
            "renewedDateTime": "2018-09-26T04:19:29Z",
            "resourceBehaviorOptions": [],
            "resourceProvisioningOptions": [],
            "securityEnabled": true,
            "visibility": null,
            "onPremisesProvisioningErrors": [],
            "owners": [
                {
                    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
                    "id": "xxxx-redacted-8000-8cb9f0d497c9",
                    "deletedDateTime": null,
                    "accountEnabled": true,
                    "ageGroup": null,
                    "businessPhones": [],
                    "city": "xxxx",
                    "companyName": null,
                    "consentProvidedForMinor": null,
                    "country": "xxxx",
                    "createdDateTime": null,
                    "department": "Human Resources",
                    "displayName": "Adam G",
                    "employeeId": null,
                    "faxNumber": null,
                    "givenName": "Adam",
                    "jobTitle": "Senior Human Resource Manager",
                    "legalAgeGroupClassification": null,
                    "mail": null,
                    "mailNickname": "adamg",
                    "mobilePhone": "xxxx",
                    "onPremisesDistinguishedName": null,
                    "onPremisesDomainName": null,
                    "onPremisesImmutableId": null,
                    "onPremisesLastSyncDateTime": null,
                    "onPremisesSecurityIdentifier": null,
                    "onPremisesSamAccountName": null,
                    "onPremisesSyncEnabled": null,
                    "onPremisesUserPrincipalName": null,
                    "otherMails": [],
                    "passwordPolicies": "DisablePasswordExpiration",
                    "passwordProfile": null,
                    "officeLocation": "131/1105",
                    "postalCode": "98052",
                    "preferredLanguage": "en-US",
                    "proxyAddresses": [],
                    "refreshTokensValidFromDateTime": "2018-09-19T03:34:39Z",
                    "imAddresses": [],
                    "isResourceAccount": null,
                    "showInAddressList": null,
                    "state": "MH",
                    "streetAddress": "xxxxxxxe",
                    "surname": "Gily",
                    "usageLocation": "US",
                    "userPrincipalName": "adamg@xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "userType": "Member",
                    "assignedLicenses": [],
                    "assignedPlans": [],
                    "onPremisesProvisioningErrors": [],
                    "onPremisesExtensionAttributes": {
                        "extensionAttribute1": null,
                        "extensionAttribute2": null,
                        "extensionAttribute3": null,
                        "extensionAttribute4": null,
                        "extensionAttribute5": null,
                        "extensionAttribute6": null,
                        "extensionAttribute7": null,
                        "extensionAttribute8": null,
                        "extensionAttribute9": null,
                        "extensionAttribute10": null,
                        "extensionAttribute11": null,
                        "extensionAttribute12": null,
                        "extensionAttribute13": null,
                        "extensionAttribute14": null,
                        "extensionAttribute15": null
                    },
                    "provisionedPlans": []
                },
                {
                    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
                    "id": "xxxx-redacted-4824-8013-4325f68e275d",
                    "deletedDateTime": null,
                    "accountEnabled": true,
                    "ageGroup": null,
                    "businessPhones": [],
                    "city": null,
                    "companyName": null,
                    "consentProvidedForMinor": null,
                    "country": null,
                    "createdDateTime": null,
                    "department": null,
                    "displayName": "groupownertest",
                    "employeeId": null,
                    "faxNumber": null,
                    "givenName": null,
                    "jobTitle": null,
                    "legalAgeGroupClassification": null,
                    "mail": null,
                    "mailNickname": "groupownertest",
                    "mobilePhone": null,
                    "onPremisesDistinguishedName": null,
                    "onPremisesDomainName": null,
                    "onPremisesImmutableId": null,
                    "onPremisesLastSyncDateTime": null,
                    "onPremisesSecurityIdentifier": null,
                    "onPremisesSamAccountName": null,
                    "onPremisesSyncEnabled": null,
                    "onPremisesUserPrincipalName": null,
                    "otherMails": [],
                    "passwordPolicies": null,
                    "passwordProfile": null,
                    "officeLocation": null,
                    "postalCode": null,
                    "preferredLanguage": null,
                    "proxyAddresses": [],
                    "refreshTokensValidFromDateTime": "2019-01-23T18:56:43Z",
                    "imAddresses": [],
                    "isResourceAccount": null,
                    "showInAddressList": null,
                    "state": null,
                    "streetAddress": null,
                    "surname": null,
                    "usageLocation": null,
                    "userPrincipalName": "groupownertest@XXXXX.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "userType": "Member",
                    "assignedLicenses": [],
                    "assignedPlans": [],
                    "onPremisesProvisioningErrors": [],
                    "onPremisesExtensionAttributes": {
                        "extensionAttribute1": null,
                        "extensionAttribute2": null,
                        "extensionAttribute3": null,
                        "extensionAttribute4": null,
                        "extensionAttribute5": null,
                        "extensionAttribute6": null,
                        "extensionAttribute7": null,
                        "extensionAttribute8": null,
                        "extensionAttribute9": null,
                        "extensionAttribute10": null,
                        "extensionAttribute11": null,
                        "extensionAttribute12": null,
                        "extensionAttribute13": null,
                        "extensionAttribute14": null,
                        "extensionAttribute15": null
                    },
                    "provisionedPlans": []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**UPDATE 1 (to answer queries from comments)**

members and owners are both navigational properties/relationships and not direct properties for groups. You can only expand one at a time. I'll show you 3 quick api calls that can be tested from Microsoft Graph Explorer.

*expand only members* - This works as expected and returns groups as well as members for each group.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$expand=members
```

*expand only owners* - This works as expected and returns groups as well as owners for each group. Sample response shown above already.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$expand=owners
```

*expand both members and owners in a single call*

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$expand=members,owners
```

RESPONSE

**you can only expand one navigational property in a single call.. look at the error message it's quite intuitive**:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_BadRequest",
        "message": "The result of parsing $expand contained at least 2 items, but the maximum allowed is 1.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "119cf794-af56-48a0-b415-4d52c2e60e98",
            "date": "2019-02-13T02:57:13"
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2 (to answer query about expand and select together from comments)**

I don't think you will be able to $select only a few columns along with $expand in the query. This seems to be a known limitation. See the two links below for more context

1. [Query Parameter Limitations - Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#query-parameter-limitations)
2. [Another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51604124/microsoft-graph-group-query-does-not-expand-relationships-when-select-is-presen)
   Specifically, in this SO post look at comment from [Marc LaFleur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/105518/marc-lafleur) and an answer from [Dan Kershaw - MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4092015/dan-kershaw-msft)

Comment: thanks for the reply......If I need to get both owners and group members of the group.................this is not working `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$expand=owners, users`

Comment: you're welcome. Members and Owners are both navigational properties.. I don't think you will be able to expand both of them in a single call.. it will go something like `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$expand=owners,members` I will quickly test and update back my answer

Comment: @AlexMan I have updated back my answer with more detailed information at the end (including sample requests and responses).

Comment: Thanks for that Lastly how I can mention only the required details to be return under owner array. Lets say I want only id and mail details of owner how can we do that. I have seen and option called $select but it is not working somehow for me. I tried like `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$expand=owners($select=id,mail)`

Comment: @AlexMan looks like that won't work and is a known limitation.. I have updated my answer with a couple of links that give more context about that

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this has been fixed, but I was able to limit the output of the expanded owner query with this

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/?$select=displayName&$filter=resourceProvisioningOptions/Any(x:x eq 'Team')&$expand=owners($select=id,department)
```

note: this was to retrieve specific groups that belonged to Teams, but that's just a filter, I think it should work otherwise as well.